# Cellular/Network SMS integration for Quiz application

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, c#-4.0, sms

I tried with google but no success, what i want to do is to make sms poll/quiz type of thing where user can send sms to "7766" and get response like  "Welcome to ABC. reply with 1 to get you new question, 2 with help, and 3 to view your result " . this will be a a two way communication and on sending any sms will cost $10 .

Here are my question: 
How can i do that?
Do i need to ask sim [provider for tht Number (7766)
This should work from some specific country only.
I need to charge amount on entering the QUIZ.

Well as new to this, i dont see any starting point from wher i can start. I need reference or some one already did that or like this thn kindly share that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can have an ecommerce solution on your website (Paypal for example) and then once your user has paid, they have access to a portion of your site that uses an HTTP SMS API. An example of a provider of such a service would be http://www.bulksms.co.uk/w/eapi-sms-gateway.htm

These APIs allow you to send messages, receive delivery reports and receive replies (amongst other things).

It's quite a wide-ranging question though.